# Error in abs(c(deltas, deltas2)) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function - RStudio

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, random-effects, winbugs, r2winbugs

I'm trying to use the BugsNet package for NMA with contrast date.
However, when performing the random effects model operation, the message above appears.

[image: data set used]

I'm using the code below:

```r
library(BUGSnet)
osdataset1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/doacnma.xlsx", na = "NA")
contrast_prep <- data.prep(arm.data = osdataset1, varname.t = "treatment", varname.s = "study")
random_effects_model <- nma.model.contrast(
    data=contrast_prep, differences="lor", 
    se.diffs = "se", reference = "1", effects = "random",
    scale = "Log-odds ratio")
```

Comment: Check `str(osdataset1)`. Are column classes "numeric"?

Comment: No
When I put them to numeric all the values automatically change to NA, so I let them in character

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a BUGS user, but I suspect that your problem is that they are not numbers (as the error and Roland's comment states). Your numbers use comma as a decimal point, so we need to fix that.

Try:

```r
osdataset1[,c("lor", "se")] <- lapply(
  osdataset1[,c("lor", "se")],
  function(val) suppressWarnings(as.numeric(sub(",", ".", val))))
```

and then repeat your code.

The `sub` replaces the first `,` with a `.`, then we convert it to numbers with `as.numeric`. Since `as.numeric("NA")` is going to emit a warning in R, we `suppressWarnings` for that.